# I am not able to store entity using em.merge in broadleaf

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to **broadleaf** application. I am able to run application using **tomcat + mysql** integration well. Now I want to move on with the development to customize the site project as per my requirement.

I am stuck on the point of persistant in broadleaf site module. I have tried using `em.merge` that returns my entity but do not save it in database and also tried `@Transactional(value="blTransactionManager")` but It still problem persists. I have tried bellow code in *applicationContext-servlet.xml*

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="blMyStoreDao" expression="execution(* com.mycompany.dao.StoreDaoImpl.save*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="blTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="blMyStoreDao"/>
    </aop:config>
```

Here is my controller code

```
newStore.setCustomer(customer);
    newStore.setProductList(new ArrayList<ProductImpl>());
    Store getStore=store.save(em, newStore);
    System.out.println(getStore.getCustomer().getUsername());
    System.out.println("customer fetched: "+customer.getEmailAddress());
```

Here is my daoimpl code

```
 @Repository("blMyStoreDao")
    @Transactional(value="blTransactionManager")
    public class StoreDaoImpl implements StoreDao {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName="blPU")
        protected EntityManager em;



        @Transactional(value="blTransactionManager")
        public Store save(EntityManager em, Store store) {

            System.out.println(em);

            System.out.println(store.getCustomer().getUsername());
        Store s=  em.merge(store);
            return s;


        }


    }
```

But it also didn't resolve my issue.

Code runs perfectly as it should be, but it doesn't save my entity in database.

Anybody Help. Thanks In advance

Comment: Can you try em.flush() after em.merge(store) in your StoreDaoImpl and post the exception

Comment: Why on earth are you passing in the `EntityManager`? You should use the `EntityManager` instance from the dao, not the one you pass in. Next you have `@Transactional` so make sure you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration.

Comment: I have done the same but it was not injecting the em in daoimpl. another thing is about @transectional.    where <tx: annotation-driven to be defined in which xml. can you please provide the syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There isn't any reason to use `<aop:config>` especially in `applicationContext-servlet.xml` (if anywhere it should be in the root application context)
2. You should use `@Transactional(TransactionUtils.DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER` to annotate your method
3. It is likely that your class was not being scanned by Spring. In Broadleaf, there is a default component scan set up in `applicationContext.xml` to scan `com.mycompany.core`.

I would recommend verifying that your dao is actually scanned by Spring and is initialized as a Spring bean. The fact that the entity manager did not get injected indicates that it did not get loaded by Spring correctly. One way to verify this would be to add an `@PostConstruct` method and print something or set a breakpoint to verify that it gets hit.